# name clash when implementing Comparable

Tags: java, comparable, name-clash

I'm no Java expert but I can usually figure out the errors I encounter when working with it.  This particular one however has me scratching my head.

I have the following class (with unnecessary fluff removed for ease of reading this post)

```
package miui.content.res;

import android.app.ActivityManagerNative;
import android.app.IActivityManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ExtraConfiguration
    implements Comparable<ExtraConfiguration>
{
    public int themeChanged;

    public int compareTo(ExtraConfiguration that)
    {
        return this.themeChanged - that.themeChanged;
    }
}
```

To me, this seems pretty straight forward but upon compilation I get the following error:

```
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/src/miui/content/res/ExtraConfiguration.java:2: 
name clash: 
    compareTo(java.lang.Object) in miui.content.res.ExtraConfiguration and 
    compareTo(T) in java.lang.Comparable<miui.content.res.ExtraConfiguration> 
    have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
```

I did some brushing up on the concept of erasure, and the compareTo() method I show in the code snippet is the only one in the ExtraConfiguration class.  At this point I am not sure what the issue is.

This particular class is from an Android framework for a ROM known as MIUI which I am trying to duplicate from some decompiled source.  In the meantime I have simply removed the 'implements Comparable

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding an [`@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation to the method? It's a long shot, I know.

Comment: @MattBall I did try that just for the hell of it, no luck with that though.

Comment: *with unnecessary fluff removed*: can you provide the there details too? With what we have now, it is becoming difficult to guess...

Comment: Good point. Specifically, does it extend anything or implement a compareTo(Object) method?

Comment: @JohnWatts It does not extend any class as shown above and no other compareTo() methods besides what I have shown in the post (I made sure to mention this in there as well).

Comment: @Nivas the fluff as I called is really just a bunch of constants and some simple helper methods for other classes to call upon.  I've added the imports to my original post since I saw mention of there being a possible conflict with one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this to get around it, but I can't explain why you are getting the error:

```
public class ExtraConfiguration
    implements Comparable<Object>
{
    public int themeChanged;

    public int compareTo(Object that)
    {
        if (!(that instanceof ExtraConfiguration)) {
            throw new ClassCastException();
        } else {
            return compareTo((ExtraConfiguration) that);
        }
    }

    public int compareTo(ExtraConfiguration that)
    {
        return this.themeChanged - that.themeChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does indeed work.  I'm scratching my head as to why it complained but it's time to move on and squash bigger bugs.  Thank you for providing this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `@Override` to the `compareTo` signature.